# Approach to encoding/decoding nontrivial property of a class in Swift

Tags: swift, encoding, tuples, decoding, nscoding

## Original Post

I have a class that I'm using NSCoding to encode and decode. I get how to encode basic types like a number or a String, and I'm even chaining NSCoding compliant classes. I also get how to encode an array of these basic types.

What I'm stumped on right now is encoding a combination of strings, arrays, and pairs. Specifically, I'm trying to encode a property defined like this

```
var configuration: [([String], String)]
```

An example of some entries in this configuration property could be visualized like this:

```
configuration[0] = (["config1", "config2"], "2 configuration options")
configuration[1] = (["config1", "config2", "config3"], "3 configuration options")
```

So my hangup is how to encode this as a pair. I'm thinking of splitting the array of the pair into 2 parallel arrays. Then I'd encode those as `[[String]]` (which I think I know how to do) and `[String]`. I'd just encode them with 2 separate string keys like `"configuration0"` and `"configuration1"` (for the `.0` and `.1` parts of the pair). Then I could decode them from those string keys and re-pair them together.

Is there a better way to encode/decode this?

#### EDIT (response to zaph's answer):

I've tried to encode it using vanilla encodeObject. Here's the code:

```
var configuration: [([String], String)] = Array<([String], String)>(count: 2, repeatedValue: ([],""))
var firstConfig: ([String], String) = (["config1", "config2"], "2 configuration options")
var secondConfig: ([String], String) = (["config1", "config2", "config3"], "3 configuration options")
configuration[0] = firstConfig
configuration[1] = secondConfig
coder.encodeObject(configuration, forKey: "configuration")
```

And the error I get is: `Cannot invoke 'encodeObject' with an argument list of type '([([String], String)], forKey: String)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the information from Zaph's answer and his comments, I'm submitting my own solution as a standalone answer.

Because `configuration` is an array of tuples, you won't be able to use `encodeObject` because tuples are not supported by `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

As per "The Swift Programming Language" [footnote on tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329):

> Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple. For more information, see Classes and Structures.

The tuple can be represented as a class with 2 properties: one for the first part and one for the second part. While the extra boilerplate to make it a class and conform to NSObject and NSCoding is a lot, it makes the object more flexible for future use, so it has its trade-offs.

I created [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/timfuqua/868a2747fd7a481ab48e) to show it in action with a sample project. Simply replace a new Single View Application project's `ViewController.swift` with this file and run (class object defined at the top of the file).

The first time you run it there is no stored data on `viewDidLoad`, and sample data will be created and stored on `viewDidAppear`. Run it again and you'll see that on `viewDidLoad` the stored data is loaded properly. You can uncomment the lines that remove the data from `NSUserDefaults` and run again to reset the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `encodeObject` for `configuration` if all that is contained are `NSCoding` compliant objects.

It `configuration` is an array that contains arrays of strings and strings there should be no problem.

Comment: I've seen weird issues with tuples before, and I think that's at the root of this issue too. When I try to just encode it normally, I get this error: Cannot invoke 'encodeObject' with an argument list of type '([([String], String)], forKey: String)'

Comment: Oops, tuples, they should not be used in data structures, from the Apple iBook *Swift*:  “Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Comment: I think that just brings me right back around to my original question then, where I stated: "So my hangup is how to encode this as a pair". I *technically* could turn my pair ([String], String) into it's own class with 2 properties (the first part of the pair and the second part), but this seems like a ton of overhead to encode what is essentially 2 parallel arrays contained in one array.

Comment: In particular Objective-C does not have tuples. They are not a type supported by `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Change the tuples to a arrays.

Comment: I was able to recover most of it from a tab I still had open and reword it. I've added my own answer from the rejected edit. Thanks for your advice though, as it did help me out a lot.